# Прошу помощи с регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, pcre

Имеется текст вида:

```
Общие характеристики---Операционная система--iOS 12|<br>
;Материал корпуса--Алюминий|<br>
;Вес--631 гр|<br>
;Размеры--280,6x 214,9x 5,9 мм|<br>
Экран---Тип экрана--Liquid Retina|<br>
;Экран--12,9"|<br>
;Разрешение экрана--2732×2048|<br>
;Автоматический поворот экрана--есть|<br>
;Число пикселей на дюйм (PPI)--264|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Запись видеороликов--есть|<br>
;Макс. разрешение видео--4К|<br>
;Макс. частота кадров видео--60 кадров/с|<br>
;Фронтальная камера--7 Мп|<br>
;Фотокамера--12 Мп|
```

Пытаюсь получить следующий результат:

```
Общие характеристики---Операционная система--iOS 12|<br>
Общие характеристики---Материал корпуса--Алюминий|<br>
Общие характеристики---Вес--631 гр|<br>
Общие характеристики---Размеры--280,6x 214,9x 5,9 мм|<br>
Экран---Тип экрана--Liquid Retina|<br>
Экран---Экран--12,9"|<br>
Экран---Разрешение экрана--2732×2048|<br>
Экран---Автоматический поворот экрана--есть|<br>
Экран---Число пикселей на дюйм (PPI)--264|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Запись видеороликов--есть|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Макс. разрешение видео--4К|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Макс. частота кадров видео--60 кадров/с|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Фронтальная камера--7 Мп|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Фотокамера--12 Мп|
```

Нужно именно регулярное выражение.

Comment: *Нужно именно регулярное выражение*  - если это не домашнее задание, то гораздо проще сделать без regex

Comment: Объясню суть. Наполняю интернет-магазин.
В плагине парсинга есть поддержка замены текста.
Встроенная - очень мало функций и regex.
Если вынесу текст за пределы плагина - теряются спецсимволы.

Comment: Наверное, стоит уточнить язык и поддержку функции наряду со строкой замены.

Comment: https://simplepars.top/index.php?page=note&note_id=9

Comment: Попробовал предложить решение на JavaScript, но не уверен, сработает ли оно с вашим бекендом.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку автор плагина даёт ссылку на PCRE, трудно судить, какой язык и движок будет использоваться и какой версии.

Например, последние версии движков JavaScript поддерживают lookbehind assertions с квантификаторами неопределённой длины. Если такая поддержка есть, можно попробовать такое решение:

```js
const str = `
Общие характеристики---Операционная система--iOS 12|<br>
;Материал корпуса--Алюминий|<br>
;Вес--631 гр|<br>
;Размеры--280,6x 214,9x 5,9 мм|<br>
Экран---Тип экрана--Liquid Retina|<br>
;Экран--12,9"|<br>
;Разрешение экрана--2732×2048|<br>
;Автоматический поворот экрана--есть|<br>
;Число пикселей на дюйм (PPI)--264|<br>
Мультимедийные возможности---Запись видеороликов--есть|<br>
;Макс. разрешение видео--4К|<br>
;Макс. частота кадров видео--60 кадров/с|<br>
;Фронтальная камера--7 Мп|<br>
;Фотокамера--12 Мп|
`;

const regexp = /(?<=(^[^;\n].+?---)(?:.+?\n));/gms;
const replacement = '$1';

console.log(str.replace(regexp, replacement));
```

Comment: Спасибо. Здесь работает - вижу.
У меня нет. Заменяется на пустое значение.

{reg[#/(?<=(^[^;\n].+?---)(?:.+?\n));/gms#]}|$1

Так это выглядит в плагине

Comment: Да, я сомневался. Там, кажется, PHP на бекенде, не уверен, что он это поддерживает (обычно, заглядывание назад не поддерживает квантификаторы неопределённой длины). Но у вас. кажется, ещё удвоенные ограничители, оба `#` можно убрать. Правда, в справке по ссылке, кажется, не указано, как использовать модификаторы, вроде `/gms`.

Comment: В данном случае символ # - экран. Автор оекомендует.

Comment: Тогда можно убрать косые черты рядом с этими символами, у них ведь та же функция, согласно справке по ссылке. `{reg[#(?<=(^[^;\n].+?---)(?:.+?\n));#gms]}|$1`

Comment: Увы, не работает. Пустое значение возвращает.

Comment: Если у вас есть связь с разработчиком плагина, лучше тогда узнать у него: что используется на бекенде, поддерживаются ли заглядывания назад с кванторами неопределённой длины и как передавать модификаторы вроде `/gms`. Иначе мы будем тыкать наугад, к сожалению.

Comment: Связался. Объяснил. Ткнул носом сюда
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php

Тема общения - https://opencartforum.com/topic/123017-podderzhka-simplepars-universalnyy-parser-dlya-im/?do=findComment&comment=1617702

Comment: Как удалось выяснить, не работает ваш метод потому что он на java, а нужно php.

https://regex101.com/

По ссылке пробовал переделать в PHP, но ругается на +?.
К сожалению недостаточно познаний, что бы разобраться.
Если сможете помочь - буду очень признателен.
Модификаторы работают у автора плагина.

Comment: К сожалениию, я не знаю PHP и диалект регулярок PCRE, в той его части, которая отличается от JavaScript.Судя по тому, что ругается оно как раз на +? и что в справке по ссылке (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php) говорится «Сами утверждения 'назад' ограничены так, чтобы все подстроки, которым они соответствуют, имели фиксированную длину» — мой способ, увы, в принципе не подходит. Уточните в вопросе, что регулярка должна быть на PCRE, поддерживаемом в PHP, возможно, кто-то из знатоков в этой области поможет. Или перезадайте вопрос с добавочными метками `php` и  `pcre`.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Еще раз добрый вечер.
Как это сделать без регулярки?
Только чуть иначе. В примере текст разделен на строки, а нужно что бы отработало тоже самое, но если все 1 строкой, и строк много.

Comment: Если без регулярки, то при помощи кода? На каком языке писать код? Если опять PHP, то я ведь его не знаю. Если на JavaScript, то я не очень понимаю вашу ситуацию, куда и как этот код подключать. Вам в комментариях к вопросу предлагали сделать без регулярки, может, там спросить? Если вам долго не будут отвечать, попробуйте перезадать вопрос с этими метками. Дело в том, что он уже ушёл в историю и специалисты по PHP и PCRE, которые мониторят метки каждый день, до него могут не докопаться. Я, правда, не знаю, не противоречит ли такое дублирование правилам сайта. Можно сначала этот вопрос удалить.